# css background property

Tags: html, css

When you click on image in facebook ,  a box pos-up but the rest entire background gets covered by blackish transparent layer. what effect is that ? can it be applied using css ?

Comment: [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) ?

Comment: Please do search as light box , you will get numerous working examlpe, its very easy to implement.

Comment: How about this Example links 

http://kilianvalkhof.com/uploads/lightbox/  and  http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#">Open FancyBox</a>
<div class="fancybox">
<div class="content">
    <div class="close">x</div>
</div>
</div>​
```

and jQuery:

```
$(".fancybox").hide();
$("a").click( function() {
$(".fancybox").show();
});
$(".close").click( function() {
$(".fancybox").hide();
});
```

CSS:

```
.fancybox {
background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
.content {
    width:600px;
    background:#fff;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.close {
    position:absolute;
    font-size:22px;
    top:2px;
    right:15px;
    font-family:Arial;
}
.close:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}​
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/YnQbY/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin:

//www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Answer (score 0):

It certainly can be applied using css:

here is the css for a black overlay:

```
.overlay{
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

the z-index indicates that the overlay is positioned above all other elements, the element (the image frame on Facebook) that should be on top of the overlay must have a z-index with value 1002 or more.

the -moz-opacity is the opacity for the overlay with firefox, the opacity for the overlay with chrome, safari,... and the filter is for an overlay with IE.

I have created a project with a similar issue, I created a div with class overlay that was initially hidden, and when clicked on a button the visibility was set to visible. The I've put an iFrame on top of the div overlay (with z-index 1002).

this was the css for my overlay:

```
.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    padding: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 6px solid #E1143C;
    background-color: rgba(228,208,150,1);
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and following jQuery:

```
function showForm() {
    $(".black_overlay").show(200);
    $(".white_content").show(500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes. That effect can be done using only css.

If you have any **id** or **class** applied to that element. Then do this -

```
#transparentLayer {
   opacity:0.5; //for non-IE
   color:#000;
   filter: alpha(opacity=50); // for IE
}
```